# Confusion with output of negation operator in Java

Tags: java

```
byte x=3;
x=(byte)~x;
System.out.println(x);
```

I was confused between the output being 4 or 0 but the output is coming to be -4.
How is that ??

Comment: ~ is not the negation operator.

Comment: See my answer I tried to explain .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple !!
~a = -a - 1

Since the value of a = 3, the answer must be -4. You can check with other values too.

Answer (score 2):

On a byte 3 is represented as `00000011`. Then `~3` is `11111100` which is a negative number (starts with `1`).

Comment: but then it should print the equivalent of 11111100 which i don't think is -4 ?

Comment: @user3020666 You have to do the 2' complement of `11111100` (because it starts with a 1 so it's negative). `11111100`'s 2 complement = 4.

Answer (score 2):

See the [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

> The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it
>   can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1"
>   and every "1" a "0". For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying
>   this operator to a value whose bit pattern is "00000000" would change
>   its pattern to "11111111".

What is 3 in binary? It's 0000 0011.

What's ~3? It's 11111100, which is -4 (Two's complement).

Note, `~` is not an *negation*, it's an *operator*.

Answer (score 0):

bit 3 = `0000 0011`
x = 3
~x = `1111 1100`

the `~` is the bitwise not.  So when the first value in the bit string is a `1` it is a negative

Answer (score 0):

~ is reversing a Bit operator.

Bit reversal consists of reversing the value of a bit. If the box contains 1, you can reverse it to 0. If it contains 0, you can reverse it to 1. To support this operation, the Java language provides the bitwise negation operator represented with the ~ symbol.

```
3   --> 00000011

~3  --> 11111100
```

As it's a 2's complement number, the first bit being one means that it's a negative number.

11111100=-4

To verify see below:

```
00000011 <- reversing 
+      1<- adding 1
00000100 =4
```